# HTML5 and JavaScript Animating Rectangles?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement this "linked list animation" where users will be able to choose colors of rectangles and it will appear as if they are in a linked-list-type of diagram.

I am having trouble formulating some type of loop that would change the position of the rectangles once they are placed on the page? My code currently, is counting the amount of times that they click the "Insert button" and then according to the count would draw the rectangle on the page. I definitely know that this is not the most efficient way of doing it, and I would like some help on how I can make this better? A for-loop, an array? My code is shown below, it is heavily dependent on if & else statements right now, which isn't the best if I want to delete nodes in the future... please help.

**BASICALLY: I would like to add rectangles to the ends of another after the user clicks the button "Insert". How can I do this without depending on if-else statements? How can I put a loop into here?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type='text/css'>
            body {
            font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.4em;
                }
                #left_column{
                    float: left;
                    width:50%;
                }
                #right_column{
                    float:right;
                    width:50%;
                }

                #Container{
                width: 100%;
                height: 400px;
                position: relative;
                background: yellow;
                }

        </style>


    <title>Rainbow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <h1 class="Title">rainbow</h1>
    </div>
    <div id = "left_column">
        <div id = Container>
            <canvas id = "panel"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id = "right_column">
            <select id = "colorNodes" style="margin-left: 10px">
                <option value = "red">red</option>
                <option value = "blue">blue</option>
                <option value = "green">green</option>
                <option value = "orange">orange</option>
            </select>
            <button onclick ="insertNode()" style="margin-left: 10px">Insert</button>   
            <button onclick = "searchNode()" style="margin-left: 10px">Search</button>  
            <button onclick = "deleteNode()" style="margin-left: 10px">Delete</button>  

    </div>

    <script>
        var count = 0; 

        function insertNode(){
            var e = document.getElementById("colorNodes");
            var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            console.log("var f is " + f);

        if(count == 0){
            if(f == "red"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff3535";
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
                } 
            } else if(f == "blue"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#60b2ff";
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
                } 
            } else if(f == "green"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#6ce2a5";
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
                } 
            } else if(f == "orange"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffb135";
                    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
                } 
            }
        } else if (count == 1){ 
            if(f == "red"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff3535";
                    ctx.fillRect(190, 20, 190, 100);
                } 
            } else if(f == "blue"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#60b2ff";
                    ctx.fillRect(190, 20, 190, 100);
                } 
            } else if(f == "green"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#6ce2a5";
                    ctx.fillRect(190, 20, 190, 100);
                } 
            } else if(f == "orange"){
                count++;
                var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
                if(canvas.getContext){
                    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffb135";
                    ctx.fillRect(190, 20, 190, 100);
                } 
            }
        } 
    } 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Who down-voted this? Why? I am trying to ask for help here, it is not for a class. Merely just curious about how I can implement this without using a bunch of if & else statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would try to not repeat any code unless I could not think of another way.

I would also use a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) in this case.

```js
var count = 0;

function insertNode(){
    var e = document.getElementById("colorNodes");
    var f = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    console.log("var f is " + f);
    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("panel");
    if (! canvas.getContext) {
        console.log("no canvas context");
        return;
    }
    if (count > 1) {
        console.log("count > 1");
        return
    }
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var fRect = {
                  0:[20, 20, 150, 100],
                  1:[190, 20, 190, 100],
                };
    var fColor = null;
    switch(f) {
        case 'red' :
            fColor = "#ff3535";
            break;
        case 'blue' :
            fColor = "#60b2ff";
            break;
        case 'green' :
            fColor = "#6ce2a5";
            break;
        case 'orange' :
            fColor = "#ffb135";
            break;
        default :
            console.log("invalid color selection");
            return;            
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = fColor;
    ctx.fillRect(fRect[count][0],fRect[count][1],fRect[count][2],fRect[count][3]);
    count++;
    return;
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
}
#left_column{
    float: left;
    width:50%;
}
#right_column{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}
#Container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1 class="Title">rainbow</h1>
</div>
<div id = "left_column">
    <div id = Container>
        <canvas id = "panel"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "right_column">
    <select id = "colorNodes" style="margin-left: 10px">
        <option value = "red">red</option>
        <option value = "blue">blue</option>
        <option value = "green">green</option>
        <option value = "orange">orange</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick ="insertNode()" style="margin-left: 10px">Insert</button>
    <button onclick = "searchNode()" style="margin-left: 10px">Search</button>  
    <button onclick = "deleteNode()" style="margin-left: 10px">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this worked out! storing in arrays and switch-statements (-: